# SQL Server : select IF NOT EXISTS comparing date and time in 3 related tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 tables, and I want to select all names, unless they have a block that covers a certain time frame of the game they have entered. For example, Jane has a block on game 2, which starts at 11:00, so she is **not** available for **any** game that starts at 11:00. She is available at 8:00, so she will be selected for game 1.

Officials tbl

```
RefId      Name
---------------------  
1          Jack
2          Sam
3          Jane

Games tbl                           Blocks tbl

GameId    GameDate/Time          BlockId    RefId    GameId
-------------------------        ------------------------------
1         8/21/2021 8:00            1         2       1
2         8/21/2021 11:00           2         3       2
3         8/21/2021 11:00
```

Desired output

```
If Game 1 is selected: Jack Jane
If Game 2 is selected: Jack, Sam
If Game 3 is selected: Jack, Sam
```

I have tried similar SQL to the following and I am unable to get desired result:

```
Select a.GameId, a.GameDate o.Name 
From Games a 
Left Outer Join Blocks b On a.GameId = b.GameId 
Left Outer Join Officials o On b.RefId = o.RefId
Where not exists ---the DateTime of the block = DateTime of the game
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schema:

```
create table Officials (
   [Id] int identity not null,
   [Name] nvarchar(255),
   constraint PK_Officials primary key (Id)
)

create table Games (
   Id int identity not null,
   StartOn datetime,
   constraint PK_Games primary key (Id)
)

create table Blocks (
   Id int identity not null,
   OfficialId int not null,
   GameId int not null,
   constraint PK_Block primary key (Id),
   constraint AK_Block unique (OfficialId, GameId),
   constraint FK_Block_Officials foreign key (OfficialId) references Officials (Id),
   constraint FK_Block_Games foreign key (GameId) references Games (Id),
)

insert into Officials ([Name]) values 
('Jack'), 
('Sam'), 
('Jane')

insert into Games (StartOn) values 
('2021-08-21 08:00'), 
('2021-08-21 11:00'),
('2021-08-21 11:00')

insert into Blocks (OfficialId, GameId) values 
(2, 1),
(3, 2)
```

- `Blocks.Id` is unnecessary, you can have composite primary key from foreign keys.
- I removed unnecessary game prefixes from the game table
- I renamed primary keys to be less confusing (for example at first look it is not clear if `Officials.RefId` is primary or foreign key so I renamed it to `Officials.Id`.

Query:

```
-- Game for which we want to display free officials.
-- 1: Jack, Jane
-- 2: Jack, Sam
-- 3: Jack, Sam
declare @gameId int = 3

-- Get datetime when the game starts.
declare @gameStartOn datetime =
(
    select g.StartOn
    from dbo.Games g
    where g.Id = @gameId
)

-- Get all officicals not blocked for specified game start.
select * from dbo.Officials o 
where o.Id not in (
    -- Get all officials blocked for specified game start.
    select o.Id
    from dbo.Blocks b
    join dbo.Officials o on b.OfficialId = o.Id
    join dbo.Games g on b.GameId = g.Id
    where g.StartOn = @gameStartOn
)
```

Comment: I liked how you declared a variable and then used that in the equation. Thank you I learned a lot and this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In common table expression part I have joined Games and Blocks table to get the list of games along with respective the blocked RefId.

```
select b.RefId,g2.GameId from Games g inner join Blocks b
                     on g.GameId=b.GameId
                     inner join Games g2
                     on g.GameDate_Time=g2.GameDate_Time
```

Then with `not exists` I have removed those RefId from Officials table for a particular game.

DB-Fiddle:

Schema and insert statements:

```
create table Officials( RefId int,      Name varchar(50));
insert into Officials values(1,          'Jack');
insert into Officials values(2,          'Sam');
insert into Officials values(3,          'Jane');

create table Games(GameId int,    GameDate_Time   datetime);       
insert into Games values(1,         '8/21/2021 8:00');            
insert into Games values(2,         '8/21/2021 11:00');           
insert into Games values(3,         '8/21/2021 11:00');                

create table Blocks(BlockId int,    RefId int,    GameId int);
insert into Blocks values(1,         2,       1);
insert into Blocks values(2,         3,       2);
```

Query for Game 1:

```
with BlockGames as
(
        select b.RefId,g2.GameId from Games g inner join Blocks b
                 on g.GameId=b.GameId
                 inner join Games g2
                 on g.GameDate_Time=g2.GameDate_Time
)
Select * from Officials o
where not exists
        (
          select 1 from BlockGames bg
          where o.RefId=bg.RefId and GameId=1
        )
```

Output:

| RefId | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Jack |
| 3 | Jane |

Query for Game 2:

```
with BlockGames as
(
        select b.RefId,g2.GameId from Games g inner join Blocks b
                 on g.GameId=b.GameId
                 inner join Games g2
                 on g.GameDate_Time=g2.GameDate_Time
)
Select * from Officials o
where not exists
        (
          select 1 from BlockGames bg
          where o.RefId=bg.RefId and GameId=2
        )
```

Output:

| RefId | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Jack |
| 2 | Sam |

Query for Game 3:

```
with BlockGames as
(
        select b.RefId,g2.GameId from Games g inner join Blocks b
                 on g.GameId=b.GameId
                 inner join Games g2
                 on g.GameDate_Time=g2.GameDate_Time
)
Select * from Officials o
where not exists
        (
          select 1 from BlockGames bg
          where o.RefId=bg.RefId and GameId=3
        )
```

Output:

| RefId | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Jack |
| 2 | Sam |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c9929a99fcce3bc75acbfaa1913841c0)*

Answer (score 0):

Just add your datetime check to the left join. If the joined table's fields are null, then no such pair exists.

```
Select a.GameId, a.GameDate o.Name From Games a 
Left Outer Join Blocks b On a.GameId = b.GameId or a.DateTime = b.DateTime
Left Outer Join Officials o On b.RefId = o.RefId
where b.DateTime is null
```

Answer (score 0):

and then there's this approach, to find which officials are available for which games, over all games and officials:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
        SELECT g.GameId, g.GameDate, o.RefId, o.Name
          FROM Games     AS g
          JOIN Officials AS o
            ON NOT EXISTS (
                      SELECT 1 FROM Blocks AS b
                               JOIN Games  AS g2
                                 ON g2.GameDate = g.GameDate
                                AND b.RefId     = o.RefId
                                AND b.GameId    = g2.GameId
                   )
     )
SELECT list.GameId, LEFT(names , LEN(names)-1) AS names
  FROM cte1 AS list
 CROSS APPLY (
          SELECT Name + ','
            FROM cte1 AS t
           WHERE list.GameId = t.GameId
             FOR XML PATH('')
       ) grp (names)
 GROUP BY list.GameId, names
;
```

Just add `WHERE GameId = <n>` to the outer query expression to restrict the output to a specific game: `WHERE GameId = 2` for just game 2.

Result (updated):

```
+--------+----------------+
| GameId | Available_Refs |
+--------+----------------+
|      1 | Jack,Jane      |
|      2 | Jack,Sam       |
|      3 | Jack,Sam       |
+--------+----------------+
```

[Working Example (**updated**)](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a857a4604d01366b92c4f65f9268d3a6)

Answer (score 0):

You need to join `Officials` with LEFT joins to `Blocks` and 2 copies of `Games` and return the unmatched rows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.*
FROM Officials o
LEFT JOIN Blocks b ON b.RefId = o.RefId
LEFT JOIN Games g1 ON g1.GameId = b.GameId
LEFT JOIN Games g2 ON g2.GameDate = g1.GameDate AND g2.GameId = ?
WHERE g2.GameId IS NULL;
```

Or, with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM Officials o
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM Blocks b 
  INNER JOIN Games g1 ON g1.GameId = b.GameId
  INNER JOIN Games g2 ON g2.GameDate = g1.GameDate AND g2.GameId = ?
  WHERE b.RefId = o.RefId
);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2dd706939620c0c54f67a8882d1afb96).